# AWS ALB how to set a redirect from subdomain to same subdomain on a different host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-alb

I want to set a redirect rule on AWS Application Load Balancer. I added Route53 entries to assign ALB for domains. When I try to set a redirect rule on ALB listener it supports Subdomain conditions but only allows to set "Host" for action part.

What I want to do is set a wildcard condition and then redirect that subdomian to same subdomain on different host.

For example:

```
www.example.net -> www.example.com
test.eaxmple.net -> test.example.com
prod.example.net -> prod.example.com
```

We have different subdomains and couple more will be added every month so I don't want to assign one by one. Instead expect ALB to get a wildcard domain and redirect it to same domain. And I don't want to assign an EC2 server just for this single job and create a bottleneck with it.